# How to set google cloud environment variables (TF_VAR_org_id and TF_VAR_billing_accountHEy )?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, terraform

So, I am trying to set up a Google Cloud Network using Terraform. I am following the guide by Dan Isla who is a Google Cloud Solution Architect (URL: https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/managing-gcp-projects-with-terraform).

I am stuck at the part where I have to set the environment variables `TF_VAR_org_id` and `TF_VAR_billing_account`. I looked for them on the console but didn't have any luck. I also tried the following commands as suggested in the guide but I get a permission-denied error.

```
gcloud organizations list
gcloud beta billing accounts list
```

[image]

What do you suggest I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Looks like you do not have enough permissions, you need to talk with the Organization Administrator. Who should have access to the billing account and the organization ID

Comment: The command that you are using to get the organization ID is correct.
    gcloud organizations list

Here is the command to get he billing account ID:
    gcloud beta billing accounts list